# Fatal error: Call to undefined function uuid_get_core_entity_info()

Tags: entities

i am facing below error when i am trying to excute my drupal site. Please help me out.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function uuid_get_core_entity_info() in E:\sitesroot\0\sites\all\modules\contrib\uuid\uuid.install on line 36

Comment: what are you doing when you see this error? we need more information

Comment: If you installed Node export relation module ? Then try once to disable this module & check. If you are not getting proper output then check this reference link : [LINK](https://www.drupal.org/node/1531908)